# Sending Email from SQL Server Agent scheduled job

Tags: email, sql, agent

I've scheduled a job in SQL Server Agent that sends the result of a query in an email. If I execute the stored procedure from SSMS, it works fine. But the SQL Server Agent is not able to send emails.

Here is the error I received.

> The following account is scheduled as owner of SQL Server Agent in the SQL Server Configuration Manager: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE.

What can I do to assign privileges to this user?

Message

> Executed as user: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE. Error formatting query, probably invalid parameters [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 22050). The step failed.

Answer (score 1):

You can also  try granting access to `xp_sysmail_format_query` to `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE`:

```
USE master
--Create user in master if necessary
CREATE USER [nt authority\system] FOR LOGIN [nt authority\system]
GO
--Grant execute to the stored procedure that's failing
GRANT EXECUTE ON [xp_sysmail_format_query] TO [NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE]
GO
```

Best thing, though, is to run the SQL Agent service under the context of a domain user that has the appropriate access to your network resources.  Doing so is much more portable than using local accounts.

Comment: You're running SQL in production without knowing how to manage the service users?